# How can I automatically get both the signal and error from edges in EELS spectra?

Tags: formula, physics, dm-script

> **Is there some DM-script function,  or any other way, to obtain both the signal integral and the error of the signal integral from a Spectrum-Image or series of background-subtracted EELS Spectra?**

I am analysing a series of EELS spectra in DigitalMicrograph. I use the normal tools in DM to get the signal counts in the different windows after background subtraction. When I analysis the spectra one at a time (for instance with EELS\Quantification…, and selecting “single spectrum”), I get the estimation of the error in addition to the spectrum signal.

For instance I get: `Signal (counts): 2.91e+004 ± 1366`.

However, if I analyse the full series of spectra in a spectrum-image or a spectrum-line (*SI\Map\Signal(Dynamics)…* or with *ELLS\Quantification*, but selecting *parent spectrum-image*), I am not able to obtain the errors, I only obtain the signal counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no script-access to this functionality. However, one can easily do the maths oneself.

The error given in the EELS analysis (*GMS 2*) is just the uncertainty from the detector readout calculated by Poisson statistics, i.e. `Sqrt(N)` where `N` is the integrated intensity of the according energy region (before background subtraction). If intensity calibration is present, it is taken into account.